# How to compile tesseract baseapi.h with MinGW on window?

Tags: c++, mingw, tesseract

So I want to use tesseract api on my project.
And the problem is I don't know how to compile this baseapi.h with MinGW on window.

I'm using this

```
g++ -I/[...]/project/tesseract-master/include/ -I/[...]/project/leptonica/src/ t.cpp -o t
```

and got

```
In file included from t.cpp:2:
/[...]/project/tesseract-master/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:33:10: fatal error: tesseract/version.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tesseract/version.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I think the problem is about version.h file, It's actually a version.h.in file

leptonica also have same problem with .h.in file

I don't know if MinGW can compile this type of file, so if there's a way or it can't pls tell me thanks.

> g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
>
> Tesseract from main branch https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
>
> Leptonica from 1.80.0 release
> https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica

Comment: Did you build it with mingw using a Makefile you generated using CMake? If not how and what binaries did you install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did not install tesseract - otherwise `version.h` (actually generated during tesseract build/compilation) would be present.

Comment: yeah the problem is me being stupid and didn't build it. thanks